# OneDrive - Missing "Sync Additional Library" option?

Tags: library, onedrive-for-business, sync, onedrive

I just upgraded my PC to Windows 10.  Previously (Windows 8.1) I was syncing both my normal OneDrive and a Sharepoint libraries.  After installing Windows 10 I installed Office 2016 One-Click from Office365 which includes OneDrive for Business.  This is the same install I was using on Windows 8.1.  Upon logging in it automatically synced my "OneDrive - Company Name folder" but I don't have the option I used to have when I right click, which was "[Sync A New Library](https://support.content.office.net/en-us/media/62bfa44a-13b0-48c3-86d6-98616806dc20.jpg)" (Screenshot from office support).

Now my context menu simply looks like this:

[image]

I tried opening the document library in IE and clicking "Sync" but it just opens this [KB Article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2903984), like I don't even have OD installed.  If I try to install using the link here, it just tells me that I already have a newer version of office installed and will have to uninstall it to continue.

How can I sync a sharepoint library?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like you are using OD for Business, but regular OD.  I have an O365 E3 license, and my OD for Business menu looks different that what you've posted.  I'm running Windows 10 x64 with Office 2016.

OneDrive for Business menu:

[image: OneDrive for Business image]

OneDrive menu:

[image: OneDrive image]